# How do I limit Get-ChildItem before it comes back with results (before a piped filter)

Tags: powershell, limit, get-childitem

While it looks like this question has been asked before, none of the answers worked to speed up the search...

Code added:

`Get-ChildItem "c:\users\???????\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome*\User Data\GRShaderCache\GPUCache*" -File | Select-Object -first 100`

On a system with .5 million files, it takes 60 seconds to return, with just 100's of files it's close to immediate.  The first 0-length file in the 60 seconds return is typically the 5th file in.  Changing the select to 1 or 1000, still takes 60 seconds, because it's being buffered before the pipe.  Sure, maybe it will load 2 million files before taking a breath, but 60 seconds is already too long.

Is it possible to limit the results of Get-ChildItem, **BEFORE** using a pipe to filter it?  If there are 16 million files I only want to query, say, the first 10 or 100.  Unfortunately, Get-ChildItem seems to fully gather the entire list of files BEFORE I can pipe it to filter on zero-length files.  Piping only helps to limit the output, not the initial search, but the only option -Filter, isn't as robust as I think it could be, unless I'm missing something.

Example case:  I need to query all of our enterprise workstations because something's going wrong in Chrome where the GrShaderCache\GPUCache folder starts filling up with zero-length files.  Millions of them.  The only limiter on the number of files is that they are generated as f_xxxxxx where the x is the hex sequence, thus FFFFFF would limit the amount to 16,777,215 files.  I suspect some enterprise-level anti-virus filter has been put in place that can cause this (basically Chrome can create the file but is denied write access, and it has nothing to do with Chrome's access rights in the folder).

While I could just clear this cache on all the workstations, the steps to do that are painful, as all chrome processes need to be killed and then the removal of the folder is a very slow process.

I also can't just filter on f_xxxxxx because they can be legitimate files, too.

Comment: `Get-ChildItem`, as most PowerShell cmdlets, stream objects. The only available built-in "pipeline stopper" we have is `Select-Object`, hence if you wanted to _"say, the first 10 or 100"_ you would `Get-ChildItem | myFilterFor0LengthFiles | Select-Object -First 100`

Comment: Sadly that doesn't truly stop it...there's no reduction in time it takes to go through all the files

Comment: So, you're basically saying that doing something like `Get-ChildItem C:\ -Recurse -EA 0 | Select-Object -First 10` will enumerate all files in your `C` drive __before__ outputting the first 10 items (which is clearly incorrect).

Comment: I don't know what -EA is for but if I run this against a remote machine with .5 million files, it takes 60 seconds to come back.  Same run with 4 files is almost immediate.:
 
Get-ChildItem "c:\users\???????\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome*\User Data\GRShaderCache\GPUCache\*" -File  | Select-Object -first 100

Comment: Basically I'm only looking for evidence of a 0-length file in a fixed location, but don't want to get "stuck" waiting for all the files, or however many files are being returned of the .5 million, and the worst-case scenario is 16 million files.

Comment: Without looking at your code there is no way to tell what you're doing wrong